# How to use hover link dynamic table data with an area of the map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, synchronized

Currently, I'm facing a problem of hover link dynamic data table with an area of the map shows on website.

The script I use for table show as below:

```
$(function () {
    $("[id*=buildingView] td").hover(function () {
        $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).addClass("hover_row");
    }, function () {
        $("td", $(this).closest("tr")).removeClass("hover_row");
    });
});
```

For the floor image as below:

```
<img src="images/classroom.png" usemap="#A1floor" style="max-width:100%; display:block;height:auto" >
<map id="image_map" name="A1floor">
    <area href="#" state="room101" shape="rect"  coords="72, 52, 258, 130">
```

I am using hover to let the dynamic table show the hover on background, the problem is I have no idea how to link the floor image with the table by using hover. How to make the table and map synchronize by using hover?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve.please edit your question. Try to put up a fiddle if possible.

Comment: i just want to make the hover at the same time when cursor move to the dynamic table row for example below:

ClassroomID  Student
 C101               john

image floor map example |1 |  | 2 |  | 3 | as location in the image
| 1  |  [coords="72, 52, 258, 130"]
| 2  |  [coords="72, 138, 259, 218"]
| 3  |  [coords="71, 317, 259, 395"]

Comment: 1.) What do you mean by make a hover? - do you want to change the background color of the row when you hover over it? 2.) Whats this dynamic table. Where is this coming from and how it is related to the image. Please Put up a fiddle!!

Comment: the floor image is fix with the location which is set as coords="72, 52, 258, 130"
dynamic table change when it get the xml  file, it related to the image when user drag the cursor on row 1 of the table classroom  it will highlight up row 1 and the location of the classroom is.
sorry if i don't describe it well please forgive thank you.

Comment: the problem is solve thank you.

Comment: @GoldAge: would you add a solution below for this old question? There tends to be a view here, and on other help sites, that the price for asking a question is to offer a solution if you resolve it yourself. It may be of help to future readers! Thanks.